# How to close a popup window using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to web development environment. I am just a beginner. I just tried to open a popup window using javascript, following is the code

```
<li>
  <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick ="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style=display='block'"><strong>Our Mission</strong>
    <em class="ico1" ></em>
  </a>
<div id="light" class="white_content">  <font color="white" ><p> SOME TEXT HERE</font>  
</div>
```

The popup window opens. When I tried to close it, it s not working. Please help me to close the popup window.

Comment: This is not a valid html (you're missing some tags).

Comment: The code you gave is not opening any window

Comment: @C.Malet <--- yeah that too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not opening any window, You are trying to show Div as pop up box
so
Add a button to close

This button should be added inside the pop up box

```
<input type="button" value="close" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style. 
display='none'" >
```